# Cite first instance of an acronym

Tags: citing, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the acronyms in the `glossaries` package such that I can do this:

```
\newacronym{MIRDD}{MIRDD}{Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram}
\gls{MIRDD}

\gls{MIRDD}
```

This stores the acronym and then prints

```
Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram (MIRDD)
MIRDD
```

However, it would be nice if I could do this:

```
\newacronym[\citep{Person2018}]{MIRDD}{MIRDD}{Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram}\gls{MIRDD}

\gls{MIRDD}

\gls{MIRDD}
```

and maybe

```
\glscite{MIRDD}
```

so that it prints:

```
Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram (MIRDD; Person et al. 2018)
MIRDD
```

and maybe

```
MIRDD (Person et al. 2018)
```

using the usual natbib stuff.

Is this possible??

I've looked through the docs and whilst there is support for prefixes there appears to be no support for suffixes or anything like this.

Comment: You can store the citation label in one of the user fields. See for example [Citations in Glossary Sample](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/cites.shtml). For suffixes, there's the post-description hook, which is enhanced by the `glossaries-extra` package, or the `long-short-user` abbreviation style, for example, [Abbreviations (With Translations) Sample](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/abbreviations-lang.shtml) which is designed for translations but could be adapted to use `\cite`. It would help to have a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to work with.

Comment: So how would one use `glossaries-extra` to add a suffix to the first instance. Indeed, how do you redefine the first instance at all?

Comment: I think with abbreviations you'd be better off using the `long-short-user` style rather than adding a suffix, as then you can include the citation within the parentheses that show the short form.

Comment: I'm getting `! Package glossaries-extra Error: Undefined abbreviation style `long-short-user`

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of `glossaries-extra`. The `long-short-user` style was added to 1.04 (2016-05-02).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is with [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtruserparen}[2]{% requires glossaries-extra v1.04+
  \glsxtrfullsep{#2}%
  \glsxtrparen
   {#1\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{#2}{;
     \expandafter\citet\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}{}}%
}

\glsdefpostdesc{acronym}{% requires glossaries-extra v1.31+
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 {~\expandafter\citep\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}%
 {}%
}

\newacronym[user1={article-minimal}]{MIRDD}{MIRDD}{Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{MIRDD}. Next use: \gls{MIRDD}.

\printglossary
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

The base `glossaries` package is implicitly loaded, but it needs to be at least version 4.23 which provides `\glscurrentfieldvalue` for use within the true part of `\ifglshasfield`. This example produces:

[image: image of document with citation included in parenthesis after the short form on first use]

The `user1` field may contain a comma-separated list of citation labels.

This example won't work well with `hyperref` as you'll end up with nested hyperlinks on first use. The simplest workaround is to disable the hyperlinks on first use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{nohyperfirst}{true}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtruserparen}[2]{% requires glossaries-extra v1.04+
  \glsxtrfullsep{#2}%
  \glsxtrparen
   {#1\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{#2}{;
     \expandafter\citet\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}{}}%
}

\glsdefpostdesc{acronym}{% requires glossaries-extra v1.31+
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 {~\expandafter\citep\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}%
 {}%
}

\newacronym[user1={article-minimal}]{MIRDD}{MIRDD}{Mid-Infrared Diagnostic Diagram}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{MIRDD}. Next use: \gls{MIRDD}.

\printglossary
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```